# How to remove the space under a div that has been displayed on a calculated height

Tags: css

I have a some div containing an image with a calculated height which enables me to display only part of the image (100%-197px). My problem is that the text under my calculated height div does not appear directly under the image but leaves an empty space.

Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/manofgod/p8b5sb0t/3/)

and Here is my code

```
<style>
#div1 {
    left: 300px;
    height: calc(100% - 197px);
    border: 1px solid black;
    background-color: yellow;
    float:left;
    overflow:hidden;
}
#div1 img{
  height:auto;
}
.wrap{
  height:100vh;
}
</style>

<div class="wrap">


  <div id="div1">
  <img src="http://externalapp.websoftghana.com/clean/decoupes/4000.jpg">
  </div>



</div>

<p>This text is supposed to appear right under the image but it goes down . How to solve it ?</p>
```

How to remove the space under a div that has been displayed  on a calculated height ?

Answer (score 2):

You can change the source ordering or change the style. As it stood, your `<p>` tag was being pushed to below the `<div class="wrapper">` element.

See codepen below:
http://jsfiddle.net/p8b5sb0t/4/

And code:

```
<div class="wrap">
  <div id="div1">
  <img src="http://externalapp.websoftghana.com/clean/decoupes/4000.jpg">
  </div>
  <p>This text is supposed to appear right under the image but it goes down . How to solve it ?</p>
  </div>
```

Comment: Exactly. Now before i mark it as final answer,  so if i get it right every other content on my page must be inside the wrap isn't it ?

Comment: I don't know the answer to that question. I don't know what else is on your page; All I can tell you is that your `div` with the class `wrapper` has a height that will get in the way of any following elements in this manner unless if they're a `child`/`descendant` element or if they're `position`ed/`transform`ed/`display`ed another way.

Comment: You must post your page in order for me to tell.